# XMLHttpRequest cannot load " " No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Origin not allowed access. Key Set-cookie

Tags: xmlhttprequest, jqxhr

I want to Show an HLS Live stream on my site, but I'm getting "XMLHttpRequest cannot load "Link".m3u8.key. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'My site' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403."

Header information:

[image: Header information]

Now this is how another site has it: (Working site)

[image: Working site]

I know it has something to do with Set-Cookie for the .m3u8 playlist to play, I also have

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

In .htaccess...
I'm a completely new to all of this but if someone can help me, that'll be much appreciated.

Comment: The link to the HLS playlist is not valid/correctly formatted hence the cookie is not being automatically set. But did you manage to fix this yet?